# Selecting not null column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, varbinary, nvarchar

I have a table with `varbinary(max)` column and `nvarchar(max)` column. One of them is null and the other has a value.

I would like to return the column that has the value as a varbinary(max) column. So far I have tried this, that does not work:

```
SELECT 
      A =  
      CASE A
         WHEN NULL THEN B
         ELSE A 
      END
FROM Table
```

Comment: COALESCE is what you need. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(A, CAST(B As varbinary(max)))
```

*UPDATE*: In response to comments (thanks) and assuming B is the `nvarchar(max)` column, I have moved the `CAST` inside the `COALESCE`

Comment: If `A` is the `nvarchar(max)` column, this would cause a double conversion for B.  I.e. from `varbinary` to `nvarchar` to match the first argument to `coalesce`, and then back again for the explicit cast

Comment: @Andomar - it doesn't matter what order the columns are in. COALESCE picks the "best" data type from all available. ISNULL uses the first data type.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: You're right, though you'll still get a double conversion.  (Looks like `nvarchar` has a higher precedence than `varbinary`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

Comment: @Andomar - agreed. It would be better to put the CAST inside the COALESCE, just against the nvarchar column.

Answer (score 2):

Try `SELECT ISNULL(A, cast(B AS varbinary(max))) FROM TABLE`

Answer (score 1):

Your case statement evaluates to the dreaded `A = NULL`:

```
CASE A WHEN NULL THEN B ELSE A END
```

Is the same as:

```
CASE WHEN A = NULL then B ELSE A END
```

One way to fix this is to use `A IS NULL`, like:

```
CASE WHEN A IS NULL THEN B ELSE A END
```

Or even simpler:

```
COALESCE(A,B)
```

Both the `when` and the `coalesce` will assume the data type of the first argument.  To cast the result to `varbinary`, you can place the `varbinary` column first, or explicitly cast:

```
COALESCE(CAST(A AS VARBINARY(MAX)),B)
```

Comment: From BOL for COALESCE "Returns the data type of expression with the highest data type precedence.". Whereas ISNULL "Returns the same type as check_expression." (where check_expression is the first argument)

Comment: Also, CASE: "Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression"

Answer (score 0):

here is the full code of create table and insert value and apply my code and only retrieve not null value

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SUPPLIER](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SUPPLIER_NAME] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ADDRESS] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [CREATE_DATE] [datetime] NULL,)

    INSERT INTO [MyPayrol].[dbo].[SUPPLIER]
           ([SUPPLIER_NAME]           
           ,[CREATE_DATE])
     VALUES
           ('Khaled Nabil'
           ,GETDATE())


declare @inumberofcolumn int

select @inumberofcolumn= count(*) 
from sys.columns where OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'supplier'

declare @nameofcolumn varchar(100)

set @nameofcolumn =''

declare @counter int

set @counter=1


declare @colname varchar(100)

declare @statment varchar(100)

declare @value varchar(100)

while @counter <=@inumberofcolumn
begin

    select @colname= COL_NAME(object_id('[dbo].[SUPPLIER]'),@counter)
    declare @data table ([value] varchar(100))

    --set @statment = 'select '+@colname+' from [dbo].[SUPPLIER]'
      insert @data exec ('SELECT top 1 '+ @colname +' from [dbo].[SUPPLIER]') 
      select @value = [value] from @data
    if @value is not  null
    begin
        if @counter = 1
        begin   
            set @nameofcolumn = @nameofcolumn + @colname
        end
        else
        begin
            set @nameofcolumn = @nameofcolumn + ','+ @colname
        end
    end
    set  @counter = @counter+1
end



execute ('select '+@nameofcolumn+' from [dbo].[SUPPLIER]')
```